# Why can't I link this simple assembly language object file?

Tags: gcc

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Terminal.

I am doing an assembly language exercise for a class.  I wanted to try running this in terminal, but I am unable to link this file.  [I think 'link' is the correct terminology for using the command `gcc -o ex71 ex71.s` but I am new to assembly language and GNU/Linux so I may be mistaken].  Below is my .s file.

I first type `as -gstabs -o ex71.o ex71.s` into terminal which is what my textbook does [to create an **object file** right?].  Then I type the `gcc -o ex71 ex71.s` command.  Then I would type `./ex71` but I get a long error with `gcc -o ex71 ex71.s` telling me `relocation ## has invalid symbol index ##`.  At the end of the error, it says `undefined reference to 'main'`.

Sample of the output error message demonstrating its form:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
```

---

Source code:

```
# ex71.s
# Minimum components of a C program, in assembly language
# Copied from Bob Plantz
# 
# comment lines placed to correspond with textbook

    .text
    .globl  f
    .type   f, @function
f:  
    pushq   %rbp            # save caller's frame pointer
    movq    %rsp, %rbp      # establish our frame pointer

    movl    $0, %eax        # return 0 to caller

    movq    %rbp, %rsp      # restore stack pointer
    popq    %rbp            # restore caller's frame pointer
    ret             # back to caller
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have your object file (generated, as you correctly surmised, using `as -gstabs -o ex71.o ex71.s`), so to link it you should be using:

```
gcc -o ex71 ex71.o
```

See, for example, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441877/how-do-i-link-object-files-in-c-problems-with-compilation).

The `undefined reference to main` from GCC is because it expects a `main` function when told to create an executable. As I understand it (I might be wrong, I have never done assembly language programming), you need either a `_start` function (in which case you'd use `ld`) or a `main` function, (in which case you'd use GCC). So Replace `f` with `_start` and do:

```
ld -o ex71 ex71.o
```

Or replace `f` with `main` and do:

```
gcc -o ex71 ex71.o
```

After that I get a segfault, but that's up to you to debug. My understanding of this ends here. :)